# How can I make a HTML table with headers in one vertical column?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to make a HTML file that has the headers in one vertical column, and the data in the column to the right. There will only be 2 columns in total. I've looked at the html docs and seen stuff about scope, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it in this context. Example:

[image]

Comment: Do they have to be headers as in <th> elements or do you just want them to be bold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML is pretty straightforward, just be sure to use the [`[scope]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#attr-th-scope) to specify the correct orientation of the table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">City</th>
            <td>$city</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Latitude</th>
            <td>$latitude</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Longitude</th>
            <td>$longitude</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Country</th>
            <td>$country</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the docs for the `[scope]` attribute:

> The *row* state means the header cell applies to some of the subsequent cells in the same row(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the tables with  elements proceeded by  elements like so:

```
<table> 
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Category 1</th><td>data1</td>        
</tr>   
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Category 2</th><td>data2</td>        
</tr>  
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Category 3</th><td>data3</td>         
</tr>
```

Here is an example of it in action:

[vertical headers](http://jsfiddle.net/PrwH6/)